# Azure AD B2C - Sign In Policy - SSO and Keep Me Signed In Not Working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have recently been going through the guides at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi to try and setup a B2C system with multiple applications in one tenant, so we could use Single Sign On, utilising the Keep Me Signed In custom policy featured in the Identity Experience Framework guide and the relevant samples for that. I use the following sample for this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

However, none of these seem to be working how I need it to. If I run Contoso App and API 1 and sign in, Contoso App and Api 2 (which are part of the same tenant and run the same policies) does not pick up the SSO and asks me to sign in. This happens when I use the default signinorsignup policy (without any changes to SSO settings) or the custom keepmesignedin policy.

If I close App 1 and re open it, I am again asked to sign in (keep me signed in has been totally forgotten about).

I have not changed any code in the sample other than in the web configs to change the corresponding tenants, client ids etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: No really helpful thoughts, just commiseration.  I'm having the same problem.  I noticed, thought, that my other application which only has a 'Sign In' policy has a little box that allows you to remain signed in, so you might just try using the "Sign In" policy and a separate "Sign Up" policy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry I missed it! We ended up giving up on this due to the lack of polish and went with a.net core solution, which seems a better bet, especially now that they are building it into version 3.

Comment: Same issue here...